# What is the purpose of a JAR file without dependencies?

Tags: java, maven, jar, executable-jar, maven-surefire-plugin

I have always used an uber-jar, created using Maven, but I am starting to wonder why or how do you use JAR files without the dependencies?

What can you do with the jar file that doesn’t have dependencies? Is this to be used in environments known to already have the required dependencies? Or is it possible to install all required dependencies using that jar file and then executing it?

Comment: @DavidTejuosho (I didn't) "can", but not "are obligated to".

Comment: Usually you create an ueber jar which contains everything you need within a single jar in cases where you want to create a command like tool (for example spring boot does that) or can be done with maven-shade-plugin.. But usually you only create a single jar which contains on the classes from your `src/main/java` which will be used by others (think of a library). The user of the library can create different things another librarary or create war/ear/ueber jar etc.

Comment: For an *application*, you're right that most commonly in 2022 people will create an uber jar. Libraries don't though. Libraries need to provide the flexibility to override a transitive dependency version or omit it entirely, and you lose that ability (or at least, it becomes a lot more difficult) if the transitive dependencies are bundled. There are also other styles of deployment like to an application server like JBoss which provide some or all of the dependencies, where having an uber jar is undesirable.

Comment: in application server there is thing like `war` or `ear` for that purpose..

Answer (score 0):

If you have many JVM's running on a machine, each with its own uberjar, each jar would need to parsed separately. Each would take up its own chunk of memory. There would be no possibility of sharing code between JVM's, for efficiency.

If you instead do two things:

- Move common classes to dependent jars.
- Use Class Data Sharing (CDS) to create a system wide shared archive of those dependent jars.

This would mean a much lower memory footprint, for machines with limited memory, since common code is shared between the JVMs.

However today in 2022, where memory is cheap, and where containerised deployment is recommended, and running more than 1 JVM per machine is discouraged, using this strategy probably does not have the advantage that it used to have.

Stick with Uber Jars!

Comment: Can you explain that first part of your answer more in detail. During the startup time of the jvm all jar's on the classpath (module path) will be loaded... in particular this part: `There would be no possibility of sharing code between JVM's, for efficiency.` ? If have separate jar files? Sharing class system wide would not make sense from several perspectives because if you 100 app you need to test each up if you upgrade thos shared classes ???

Comment: Sharing classes has its upsides and downsides. Upside being that its much more memory efficient,  downside is that , as you say, it couples those 100 apps together, and a change demanded in one of those apps to the shared jar, would result in testing all 100. In 2022 where memory is cheep, this means the upsides of sharing classes is no longer worth the downsides.

Comment: Shared classes or libs as done in earlier days has shown that's simply the wrong way (with less memory available) .. in particular today with containers where sharing outside of the JVM is not even possible... And sharing code between different JVM's is not even possible; In two JVM's you can use the same classes yes but that will not save any memory because each JVM is separated (own memory). Apart from that CDS is intended to speed up startup time... Sharing classes in the sense of reusing code is something different..

Comment: I'm question this: `and running more than 1 JVM per machine is discouraged` ? Why ? JVM is a container like idea which means you can run several JVM on a single bare metal server without any problem?

Comment: Its 2022 - people used containerised platforms where 1 JVM going out of control, crashing a system can not take other JVM's with it!

Also...CDS does share code, according to Oracle :https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/vm/class-data-sharing.html

"The shared archive contains class data in the form that the Java Hotspot VM uses it. The memory that would otherwise be required to access the original class information in the runtime modular image, is not used. These memory savings allow more applications to be run concurrently on the same system"